# Words with Unicode characters in them don't appear in HTML output

Tags: python, django, utf-8

I am using Django 1.7.1 with Python 2.7, and when I try to pass a Spanish character like ñ or vowels with acute accent (á, é, etc) to my template, the entire string does not appear in the browser (or in the HTML either). I have tried the immediate solutions, that is, put

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in my `views.py` and also put

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in my template, but the characters still don't appear. It is important to mention that the webpage loads without errors, only the strings with Spanish words does not appear.

**Edit 1**

My `views.py` file looks like

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
# Create your views here.

def main_page(request):
    return render_to_response(
        'index.html', RequestContext(request,{
            'country':'Perú',
        })
    )
```

and my template `index.html` is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Webpage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> {{ country }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the browser shows an empty `<h1> </h1>` tag

**SOLVED**

I changed `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` by `# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-` and put `'country': u'Perú'` instead of `'country': 'Perú'`

tag

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

was not necessary in the template

Comment: Django in general is quite good at handling Unicode. I don't really have the time to dig into this myself, but one thing to add to your question is - how exactly are you passing the non-ascii characters to the template? Django templates should work fine if you give them Python Unicode strings. I think I remember it also accepting utf-8 bytestrings and detecting the difference, but I'm less sure about that.

Comment: You can add your own solution as an answer and accept it, to make it easier to find for future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the second argument for `render_to_response` a dictionary that is passed as the context, but you are passing in the context directly.

You can fix this two ways;

1. The recommended fix is to just use `render`, like this:

   ```
   def main_page(request):
       return render(request, 'index.html', {'country': u'Perú'})
   ```
2. If you want to use `render_to_response`, you need to qualify the second argument:

   ```
   return render_to_response('index.html',
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request,
                                                            {'country': u'Perú'}))
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, Unfortunately I got the error in both cases

(unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 0: invalid start byte (views.py, line 15)

Comment: Which text editor are you using? Are you sure that the file views.py is actually stored as utf-8?